# Making incoming call to Twilio number, I hear message from SAY verb but not tones of digits from PLAY

Tags: twilio, dtmf

Using the below code in a TWIML Bin, when I call my Twilio number I hear both SAY messages properly but just silence when I'd expect to hear the tone for [wait 1 second] 3 [wait 1 second] 3 [wait 1 second] 3 [wait 1 second] 3.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Welcome</Say>
    <Play digits="ww3ww3ww3ww3"></Play>
    <Say>Goodbye</Say>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

The terminating carrier needs to play out the DTMF. Most DTMF is sent as events ([RFC 4733](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4733)) over SIP, so it is up to the terminating carrier to extract the events and insert them into the media stream. I hear them on Google Voice and Mint Mobile when calling this TwiML.